# jQuery,PHP-upload text file,doc/docx,ppt/pptx,pdf

Tags: php, jquery

How can I upload **txt, doc/docx, ppt/pptx, pdf** and restrict all other file types while uploading file using php and jquery? Can i do it with jQuery also?

I have tried this.

```
$allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "pdf", "txt");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/txt") 
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){}
```

I need it in JQuery or a better way in PHP.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I have edited the Question..Please see that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this using php :

```
$fileTypes = array('txt','doc','docx','ppt','pptx','pdf'); // file extensions allowed
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);

if(in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes))
{
   // upload file here if the extension matches to your allowed ones.
}
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh balle balle..... :D

Answer (score 0):

jQuery validation plugin is better example for this
Here is the link [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).
Also the TYPE can vary from browser to browser so it is not really reliable.
Additionally you can use `pathinfo` function of php which will give you an array with file details like extension in it.